# Lifespan of an ASP.NET ActionFilter

Tags: asp.net, action-filter

I'm performing some logging in our ASP.NET app, using a custom `ActionFilterAttribute`.  I'm adding logging for both the income info (via `OnActionExecuting`), and outgoing (via `OnActionExecuted`).

We have a call token (GUID) that I have access to in `OnActionExecuting`, and is part of the information being logged.  I'd like the same token to be used in the logging done in `OnActionExecuted`.

My questions:

1. Is one instance of `ActionFilterAttribute` created for each incoming call?
2. Is this the same instance used for both `OnActionExecuting` & `OnActionExecuted` (allowing me to store the token as a member variable)?

Answer (score 3):

Since no one has replied, and I got an answer through my own testing, I thought I'd post an Answer here.

It turns out that an instance of the action filter is created and shared among various controller action calls.  Therefore using a member variable to share common data between a request (setting it in `OnActionExecuting`) and a response (reading it in `OnActionExecuted`) is NOT a reliable means on accomplishing what I intended.